# Determine the nonzero real number $c$ having the property that $f(c) = a$ is a relative minimum of $f(x) = x^2 - ax - c$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

Determine the nonzero real number $c$ having the property that $f(c) = a$ is a relative minimum of $f(x) = x^2 - ax - c$.

My trouble with this problem is that I substituted c into the function, and by simplifying, I got

c^2-a(c+1)-c=0

I don't know where I should go from here.

Comment: `is a relative minimum` You'll need to use that condition, too. Think at where a quadratic attains its extremum.

Comment: The simplification can be written as: $c^2-(a+1)c-a=0$. That is a quadratic equation in $c$, and you know how to solve them. Then also use the hint dxiv stated above.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum is attained at $x=c \;\; $ if $$f'(c)=2c-a=0$$
thus
$$c=\frac {a}{2} .$$
The condition

$$f (c)=a$$
gives
$$\frac {a^2}{4}-a\frac {a}{2}-\frac {a}{2}=a $$

and $$ a (\frac {3}{2}+\frac {a}{4})=0.$$

Finally
$$c\in \{-3,0\} $$

Comment: Note: the problem says "nonzero" $c$. Thus, the onlid valid $c$ would be $-3.$